# MySQL datetime where clause query help

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have is a query that updates a column called "active".  Right now my query is:

```
UPDATE MainTable
   SET active = b'0'
 WHERE lastprocessdate < '5/21/2011'
```

Unfortunately, this updates everything -- which is impossible because everything has today's date on it.  `lastprocessdate` is a `datetime` column, that originally is processed using `NOW()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

In MySQL dates are written `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
update MainTable set active = b'0' where lastprocessdate < '2011-05-21';
```

Comment: @Johan: Thanks! Good clarification.

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is a more flexible means of providing a date string for MySQL to interpret properly.